# Google cloud function deploy fails

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

when i am running the gcloud functions deploy gcp_test --trigger-resource xxx-test-123 --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize i am getting syntax error .

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3,
>   message=Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded. Is
>   there a syntax error in your code? Detailed stack trace:
>   /user_code/index.js:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename,
>   __dirname) { # index.js
>                                                                 ^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>       at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:388:24)

I am not sure why this error is appearing. I have installed npm module for @google-cloud/storage . Any help is appreciated .This function is suppose to enable stackdriver logging .
reference: https://medium.com/google-cloud/encrypting-stackdriver-logging-sinks-using-customer-managed-encryption-keys-for-gcs-ccd0b59f0a3

```js
    # index.js
            'use strict';
            const Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer;
            // Imports the Google Cloud client library
            const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
            // Creates a client
            const storage = new Storage();
            exports.moveFileToEncryptedStorage = (event, callback) => {
              const file = event.data;
              console.log(  Event ${event.eventId});
              console.log(  Event Type: ${event.eventType});
              console.log(  Bucket: ${file.bucket});
              console.log(  File: ${file.name});
              console.log(  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration});
              console.log(  Created: ${file.timeCreated});
              console.log(  Updated: ${file.updated});
            const newBucket = "xxx-test-123";
            const newBucketAndFileName = "gs://"+newBucket+"/"+file.name;
            console.log("Moving to..."+newBucketAndFileName);
            return storage
                  .bucket(file.bucket)
                  .file(file.name)
                  .move(newBucketAndFileName)
                  .then(() => {
            
                    console.log("content has been moved to "+newBucketAndFileName);
            })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.error("ERROR:"+err);
                  });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the following line `# index.js` does the trick. Keep in mind that all the console.log lines should be like the following: `console.log("  Event ${event.eventId}");`